# Edit apt.conf in Debian 7.1 for Intel 64 bit

Tags: debian

Question: Does an end user need to edit `apt.conf`, if it does not exist?

If so, how does one express the following fields in an Intel 64 bit architecture?

```
Architecture  
Architectures
```

as shown in the example at: `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/apt.conf`.

In the computer science i386 corresponds to Intel 32 bit. What does amd64 correspond to?

Do the Debian developers just use amd64 designation? And have the code further in do a, if else to probe deeper for hardware id?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you are referencing a file please quote the relevant part. That might help. The last sentence is particularly obscure, at least to me. I.e. "And have the code further in do a, if else to probe deeper for hardware id?"

Answer (score 2):

Debian uses `amd64` as the designation.

The architecture specification that is commonly known as `x86_64` was originally created by AMD and thus known as `amd64` when implemented by Debian. Intel's 64-bit architecture was called Itanium (`ia64`), not compatible with 32-bit x86 architecture (`i386`)

Eventually Intel's Itanium was "retired". Intel and others licensed AMD's 64-bit architecture. Instead of renaming it, Debian chose to continue to use `amd64` as the designation to honor AMD's contribution.

Comment: AFAIK first was Itanium, then AMD invented the 64bit extension, lastly Intel adopted this extension from AMD.

Comment: Yes. Though the migration path from `i386` to `ia64` was difficult. `amd64` was designed in part to address this.